# Start PHP script on boot

Tags: php, centos, ssh

I have two PHP scripts that I need to start on boot. I have a CentOS powered VPS, and I normally use the following command to start the scripts.

```
screen php scriptname.php
```

However, if the server crashes, how can I have the scripts start automatically on boot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your command to /etc/rc.d/rc.local

Comment: And similary thread on linuxquestions.org: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/auto-run-script-496833/ :)